# Strange behavior retrieving objects from parse in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm having an issue retrieving objects in a relationship using queries. I tried simplifying to a watered down example and was able to reproduce using a `Parent` and `Child` class.

First, I save a `Parent` object with 2 children:

```
let child1: PFObject = PFObject(className: "Child")
child1["name"] = "Child1"

let child2: PFObject = PFObject(className: "Child")
child2["name"] = "Child2"

let parent: PFObject = PFObject(className: "Parent")
parent["name"] = "Parent1"
parent.addObject(child1, forKey: "children")
parent.addObject(child2, forKey: "children")

parent.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    print("success: \(success)")
}
```

Now when the app runs and there is actual data in Parse, I'm trying to fetch it with a `PFQuery`:

```
let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Parent")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
        print("result: \(result)")
}
```

The first few times I ran, the print result gave me something like this:

```
result: Optional([<Parent: 0x7fa43356ae70, objectId: JzOgNq6Y2K, localId: (null)> {
children =     (
            {
        <Child: objectId: 98dfjhwejf, blah blah...>
    },
            {
        <Child: objectId: 34763kKJHF, blah blah...>
    }
);
name = Parent1;
}])
```

Then all of a sudden, without changing anything at all, I started only getting back an array of `objectIds` for `children`:

```
result: Optional([<Parent: 0x7fa43356ae70, objectId: JzOgNq6Y2K, localId: (null)> {
children =     (
            {
        objectId = W3XflnNQupF;
    },
            {
        objectId = dI6Ky5n7lm;
    }
);
name = Parent1;
}])
```

I also tried using `query.includeKey("children")` for the query but that didn't change anything. Any help here is much appreciated. I must be missing something obvious. I thought Parse was going to make things easier. Instead I'm wasting tons of time on something that seems so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the `Parent` class to something else made everything start working again.